# Use protected instead of private for member variables

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I always got problems with the private variable declaration.
For example FlatFileItemWrite. I would like to extend these class and overwrite the 'doRead' method. This would not work because some of the used variables are declared private. This leads to copying the complete code in an own class for overwriting one method.

Sometime even this does not work because the class extends an other class which has variables declared visible only for the same package. Then you need to copy this class also.

Then I will miss updates in the original classes with new versions. So would it not be better to use protected instead?

I can imaging only a very few reasons to use private instead of protected. For my own programs this is not an issue, I could change it on demand. But for a framework it is a pain.

with kind regards

Torsten

Answer (score 2):

If something is declared `private` within the Spring framework (or any framework for that matter), it's not considered part of the public API.  Because of that, you really shouldn't be looking to work with it directly.  Doing so really means you're forking the framework and risking not being able to upgrade seamlessly.

As the project lead for Spring Batch, I'd be interested in hearing what you had to do with the `FlatFileItemWriter` that required you to change things that are marked private.

Comment: Sorry, I mean FlatFileItemReader. Here I would like to overwrite the 'doRead' method which is marked as protected, to skip empty lines (lines only containing whitespace chars or delimiter) while reading. But as the variable lineCount is private I could not do it.

Comment: I'd have to know more about your input to be able to direct you better, but my guess is that the functionality you are describing would be filtering which is intended to be done in the `ItemProcessor`.  Another option would be to implement a custom `RecordSeparatorPolicy` that includes the empty lines in the previous record.  In the end, there are probably a number of ways to address the functionality you're requiring without changing that to be protected.  If it truly needs to be protected, I'd ask that you submit a Jira request to discuss it further here: https://jira.spring.io/browse/BATCH/

Comment: Thanks, I will raise a request in Jira and explain it in more detail.

Answer (score 0):

If the idea behind the framework was to override or extend these methods, they should have been written as being public. (be careful if a framework does not provide these methods or properties as public, since it might depend on them working in a specific way. this would be the primary reason for them being private i can think of. the secondary being that they don't matter outside that class.)

In some cases, you might not need to copy the entire class, but simply inheriting or extending it might be enough.

Comment: Yes, I would like to extend the class and overwrite a method which is protected. But this method uses variables which are private.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also looking to extend certain ItemReaders/ItemWriters to support decryption/encryption on i/o. For example, I'd like to extend StaxEventItemReaderStaxEventItemReader in order to read an encrypted stream from the resource, but the FragmentEventReader is private, so I'm unable to wrap its XMLEventReader's InputStream in a decrypter.
I faced the same issue with FlatFileItemWriter.

Comment: This seems like it should be a comment not an answer.

Comment: I don't have the reputation points to comment on the original post.

Comment: You could probably do the decryption in a custom `org.springframework.core.io.Resource` implementation.

Comment: Yeah, that's the avenue I'm pursuing now. Thanks.